# Java Spring Security ionic4 HTTP request

Tags: java, spring, typescript, spring-security, ionic3

I have a Java Springboot REST api that I'm trying to send POST requests too from an ionic4 web app. Unfortunately I'm unable to get the login post working. I either receive a HTTP status `401`, `403` or `200` when it only sends the preflight options request.

I've checked for similar posts on StackOverflow which exists such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43349948/angular-2-spring-security-csrf-token?rq=1) but they've just changed the error I'm getting. Below is what I've ended up with after taking bits from various tutorials & other SO posts.

Not sure if my error is with the Spring SecurityConfiguration or TypeScript post request.

*My Spring security config*

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .authorizeRequests()

            .requestMatchers(CorsUtils::isPreFlightRequest).permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(new RestConfig().corsFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
            .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and().addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
            .formLogin().loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .successHandler(successHandler())
            .failureHandler(failureHandler())
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable();
    }

    private AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
        return new AuthenticationSuccessHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
                httpServletResponse.getWriter().append("OK");
                httpServletResponse.setStatus(200);
            }
        };
    }

    private AuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler() {
        return new AuthenticationFailureHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException {
                httpServletResponse.getWriter().append("Authentication failure");
                httpServletResponse.setStatus(401);
            }
        };
    }

    private AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler() {
        return new AccessDeniedHandler() {

            @Override
            public void handle(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, AccessDeniedException e) throws IOException, ServletException {
                httpServletResponse.getWriter().append("Access denied");
                httpServletResponse.setStatus(403);
            }
        };
    }

    private AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint() {
        return new AuthenticationEntryPoint() {

            @Override
            public void commence(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException {
                httpServletResponse.getWriter().append("Not authenticated");
                httpServletResponse.setStatus(401);
            }
        };
    }

    private Filter csrfHeaderFilter() {
        return new OncePerRequestFilter() {

            @Override
            protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                        HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
                     CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
                     if (csrf != null) {
                         Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
                        String token = csrf.getToken();
                        if (cookie == null || token != null
                        && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                            cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
                            cookie.setPath("/");
                            response.addCookie(cookie);
                        }
                    }
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "*");
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        };
    }

    private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
        HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
        repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
        repository.setSessionAttributeName("_csrf");
        return repository;
   }
```

*My TypeScript POST*

```
onLogin(loginData: {username: string, password: string}) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(loginData.username + ":" + loginData.password));


    let body = {
        username: loginData.username,
        password: loginData.password
    }
    this.http.post('http://localhost:5000/login', body, {headers: headers, withCredentials: true})
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data => {
          console.log(data);
          console.log(data.status)
       });
  }
}
```

Error I get with the above code, I know it's not the login details since the same username & password work perfectly through swagger just not in the POST.

[image: ionic error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I solved the issue.

```
onLogin(loginData: {username: string, password: string}) {
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
  headers.append('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

  let body = `username=${loginData.username}&password=${loginData.password}`;

  this.http.post('http://localhost:5000/login', body, {headers: headers})

    .map(res => res)
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data.status);
      if (data.status == 200) {
        this.navCtrl.push(TabsPage);
      }
      else {
        this.showError("Invalid username or password");
      }

    });
}
```

*Update:*
Main issue was [URL-encoding](http://www.albionresearch.com/misc/urlencode.php) this line:

```
let body = `username=${loginData.username}&password=${loginData.password}`;
```

Thanks to [dur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5277820/dur)

Comment: can you explain what you did here to solve the issue.

Comment: Since the content type was `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` I needed to URL-encode the body (basically converting special characters to hex eg. a space becomes %20)  See http://www.albionresearch.com/misc/urlencode.php for more info